# Why is there so much spam coming from Yahoo! Mail accounts?

Tags: yahoo-mail

In the last 1-2 months, I have received spam from at least 3 or 4 friends I know with Yahoo! Mail accounts. It seems there's some systemic problem there, but I don't know what it is. Were Yahoo! Mail account passwords compromised en masse?

Comment: Are these genuine mails sent via Yahoo or merely random mails with an appropriate `From:` header?

Answer (score 2):

*Where Yahoo! mail account passwords compromised en masse?*

[Yes.](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/07/yahoo-service-hacked/)

You should be able to check if an email account was compromised in that attack, via the [Sucuri website](http://labs.sucuri.net/?yahooleak).

Comment: Thanks. Two that I just checked were not in that leak. Must be some other reason.